# Trump Impeachment tallies in the House?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, congress, impeachment, trump-impeachment

Are there any reliable tallies of those in the House that are supportive of impeachment of President Trump versus those that are not? I imagine most aren't on the public record, but curious if someone or some group has whipped the total even partially?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NYT [published](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2019/us/politics/trump-impeachment-congress-list.html) a tally on Oct 10, but it may not be exactly on the question you want, i.e. it's on "support for a formal investigation into the president’s actions, which could lead to votes on articles of impeachment" rather than just "impeachment".

[image]

> Starting in May, The Times asked every representative for his or her position and has been updating this page with each response. Inclusion in the “support” category does not mean that the member supports impeachment, only that he or she has indicated support for a formal investigation into the president’s actions, which could lead to votes on articles of impeachment.

They have nominal list on that page, but it's obviously too long to reproduce here.

---

[NPR has](https://www.npr.org/2019/06/19/733536620/who-in-the-house-is-calling-for-impeachment) a more recent one (dated Oct 22) on unconditional support for an "impeachment inquiry":

> NPR's tracker lists lawmakers who have publicly announced definitive support for an impeachment inquiry. Those lawmakers who have said they would support impeachment with some qualification — e.g., if some allegations about the president are proven true — are not counted on the list of those backing impeachment.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for not taking this expressly literally and providing this approximation.  I will wait to see if something else develops.